# IDE не видит импорт и подсвечивает его как ошибку: Cannot find module '!!raw-loader', Angular

Tags: typescript, angular, ide

Пытаюсь использовать `raw-loader` для рендеринга SVG иконок, но при импорте его, IDE подсвечивает красным, но компонент работает корректно.

Я добавил конфигурацию *custom.d.ts:*

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

И отметил его в *tsconfig.json:*

```
{
  ...
  "include": [
    "custom.d.ts"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Все работает, но я не могу понять почему IDE мой всегда подсвечивает import данный красным цветом, но при этом, зажав на <kbd>ctrl</kbd> он понимает что такой файл существует и перебрасывает меня на `custom.d.ts`. Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Потому что надо прописать require в декларации

```
declare var require: {
  <T>(path: string): T;
  (paths: string[], callback: (...modules: any[]) => void): void;
  ensure: (
    paths: string[],
    callback: (require: <T>(path: string) => T) => void
  ) => void;
};
```

Подробнее тут - https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#code-splitting-and-loading-other-resources

Comment: Где именно его прописать? Я его вроде как добавил но всё равно не сработало.

Comment: в custom.d.ts и импорт потом делать через require

Comment: @AndrewDodonov `NodeRequireFunction` является частью определений `@types/node`, который поставляется автоматически с любым Angular проектом. `ts-loader` и ссылка не имеет никакого отношения к Angular.